# Keras RNN Regression Input dimensions and architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have recently constructed a CNN in Keras (with Tensorflow as this backend) that takes stellar spectra as an input and predicts three stellar parameters as outputs: Temperature, Surface Gravity, and Metallicity. I am now trying to create an RNN that does the same thing in order to compare the two models.

After searching through examples and forums I haven't come across many applications that are similar enough to my project. I have tried implementing a simple RNN to see if I can come up with sensible results, but no luck so far: the networks don't seem to be learning at all.

I could really use some guidance to get me started. Specifically:
Is an RNN an appropriate network for this type of problem? 
What is the correct input shape for the model? I know this depends on the architecture of the network, so I guess that my next question would be: what is a simple architecture to start with that is capable of computing regression predictions?

My input data is such that I have m=50,000 spectra each with n=7000 data points, and L=3 output labels that I am trying to learn. I also have test sets and cross-validation sets with the same n & L dimensions.
When structuring my input data as (m,n,1) and my output targets as (m,L) and using the following architecture, the loss doesn't seem to decrease.

```
n=7000
L=3

## train_X.shape = (50000, n, 1)

## train_Y.shape = (50000, L)

## cv_X.shape = (10000, n, 1)

## cv_Y.shape = (10000, L)

batch_size=32

lstm_layers = [16, 32]

input_shape = (None, n, 1)



model = Sequential([
    InputLayer(batch_input_shape=input_shape),
    LSTM(lstm_layers[0],return_sequences=True, dropout_W=0.2, dropout_U=0.2),
    LSTM(lstm_layers[1], return_sequences=False),
    Dense(L),
    Activation('linear')
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])





model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=20,
      validation_data=(cv_X, cv_Y), verbose=2)
```

I have also tried changing my input shape to (m, 1, n) and still haven't had any success. I am not looking for an optimal network, just something that trains and then I can take it from there. My input data isn't in time-series, but there are relationships between one section of the spectrum and the previous section, so is there a way I can structure each spectrum into a 2D array that will allow an RNN to learn stellar parameters from the spectra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you set

```
train_X.shape = (50000, n, 1)
```

Then you write

```
input_shape = (None, 1, n)
```

Why don't you try

```
input_shape = (None, n, 1) ?
```

It would make more sense for your RNN to receive a sequence of `n` timesteps and 1 value per time step than the other way around.

Does it help? :)

**EDIT : **

Alright, after re-reading here is my 2cents for your questions : the LSTM isn't a good idea.

1) because there is no "temporal" information, there isnt a "direction" in the spectrum information. The LSTM is good at capturing a changing state of the world for example. It's not the best at combining informations at the beginning of your spectrum with information at the end. It will "read" starting from the beginning and that information will fade as the state is updated. You could try a bidirectionnal LSTM to counter the fact that there is "no direction". However, go to the second point.

2) 7000 timesteps is wayyy too much for an LSTM to work. When it trains, at the backpropagation step, the LSTM is unrolled and the information will have to go through "7000 layers" (not actually 7000 because they have the same weights). This is very very difficult to train. I would limit LSTM to 100 steps at max (from my experience).

Otherwise your input shape is correct :)

Have you tried a deep fully connected network?! I believe this would be more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. You're correct though, it makes sense for the input to be (None,n,1)

Comment: No error message; it just isn't converging. The training loss remains relatively constant and the cross-validation loss doesn't change at all.

Comment: No problem. I think my main question is whether or not RNNs can be applied to a problem such as this? My input data isn't in time-series and I'm not predicting the next value in a sequence. I am inputting data examples (which are in a sort of sequence within themselves), but I am trying to predict an output value through regression. The output can be determined from the entire spectra (input example) but is not in sequence with the input data. I hope that is somewhat clear.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to Stackoverflow. Thank you very much for you input, that makes a lot of sense and I was starting to think that this may be the case. I have tried DNNs and CNNs. The CNN seems to be the most effective, I just thought I would try something new to compare with, but maybe RNNs aren't the way to go. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I don't think they are... proof is your network isn't working. Is the DNN not working at all? For me it seems to be the best theoretically because each input will be a fixed frequency/lambda, which will make learning the properties efficient. The activations might play a big role though. Btw, are your targets binary? If yes, use sigmoids for the last activations and a binary_crossentropy as loss.

Comment: The DNN was working, although it seemed the CNN was giving better results. I will revisit the DNN now though. My understanding of NNs has improved since the last time I tried the DNN so maybe that's all it is. The targets are not binary btw. I am using 'relu' activation and 'he_normal' initialization for my fully connected layers